# Filter by disjunction and conjunction in n:m relationships

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 4 tables like this (simplified to relevant columns):

**`thing:`**
`id::numeric, some_info::text`

**`mapping:`**
`thing_id::numeric, common_property_id::numeric`

**`common_properties:`**
`id::numeric, some_info::text`

**`children_of_thing`**
`id::numeric, thing_id::numeric, other_stuff::text`

`common_properties` are properties that can be attached to `thing`s, any number of properties can be attached to any number of things (n:m).
`children_of_thing` are children of a `thing`, any thing can have any number of children (1:n).

Now I want to count all children of things that have specific properties applied. My query looks like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT children_of_thing.id) as count
     , thing.id as thing_id
FROM children_of_thing
    INNER JOIN thing ON children_of_thing.thing_id = thing.id
    LEFT JOIN (mapping
       INNER JOIN common_properties ON mapping.common_property_id = common_properties.id
    ) ON thing.id = mapping.thing_id
GROUP BY thing.id
WHERE ...
```

Now my question is: how can I select only things that have (pseudocode ahead as it does obviously NOT work like that)

```
common_property.some_info = 'foo' AND (
    common_property.some_info = 'bar' OR
    common_property.some_info = 'baz'
)
```

I know I can query for just the inner part (`'bar' OR 'baz'`) just fine as-is - the `DISTINCT` on my select takes care that I only count everything once even when two entries for the same children are returned when both conditions are true.

I can also query if ALL properties (`foo ANDbar AND baz`) are true by querying for (`foo OR bar OR baz`) and adding `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT common_property.id) = 3` (this would only get results where all three conditions yield one result each).

But how can I do both, `AND`and `OR`?

*Additional notes:* The database layout is fixed, I cannot change it with reasonalbe work. It's an already runnign system. Plus, the layout makes total sense for our application. 
On top of this, speed is critical, so I'm looking for a query as optimized as possible - I would want to avoid having a separate subquery for each Conjunction (even though that is a solution, of course).

--

Below is my actual Query, that incorporates even another intermediate table (`thing_variants` - every `thing` is of one of the variants in `thing_variants`, 1:n) and filters on the children. I have originally left all that out of the questoin as it complicates everything, but if it helps understand the entire situation, I have no need to hide it.

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT children.id) as children_count
     , things.id as things_id,
     , things.meta_info as thing_info
     , thing_variants.id as thing_variant_id
     , thing_variants.meta_info as thing_variant_info
FROM children
     INNER JOIN things ON children.thing_id = things.id
     INNER JOIN thing_variants ON things.thing_variant_id = thing_variant.id
     LEFT JOIN (mapping
        INNER JOIN properties ON mapping.property_id = properties.id
     ) ON thing_variant.id = mapping.thing_variant_id
WHERE (children.something IS FALSE)
  AND (children.another_thing IS TRUE)
  AND (children.foobarbaz IS NULL)
GROUP BY things.id
```

Comment: Your question is utterly confusing.  The properties are attached to the *things* not to the *children*.  So, all children of a given thing would have the same properties.  So, why are you counting at the children level?

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I'm not exaclty sure I udnerstand your question... My ultimate goal, at the end, is to get each `thing.id` that matches the fitlers along with the number of children that belong to that thing. This is why I count children.

Comment: If you just want the count of children, then you can probably simply remove them from the question.  They don't really add anything and counting children should be easy once you have the thing ids.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I do not always count all children. There are `WHERE`-conditions that work on additoinal fields of children, and might limit their count to 0, therefore ruling out the `thing` as well (I only need those with at least one child). I just didn't put them into the question as it would blow up the minimal example.

But if you have a solution for the problem at hand if children are left out of the question, I assume I can incorporate it into a solution for everything.

Comment: I have added my complete current query without the additional filters that the question is about to the quesiton, if it helps.